# Using a column name as a fail output in case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I'm comparing a couple of columns of ID variables pulled in from a group of files to a master list, these IDs should match across columns.  I'm using case_when to make sure they each meet the master list, but I was wondering if there was a convenient way to change the "TRUE ~" output to the column name of the value that failed the test?

Here's the basic gist,

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
c <- c(1,2, "NA", "NA")
d <- c(1,2,3,4)

example <- data.table(a,b,c,d)

example %>% mutate(
   test = case_when(
      a==b & a==c & a==d ~ "PASS",
   TRUE ~ "FAIL")
)
```

Which will do the basic job of flagging any values that fail the test, but is there a modular way to change the TRUE ~ "FAIL" output to the name of the column that produced the failure, "c" in this case?

Comment: There is a small flaw in your assumption: how do you know that there will only be one column different? What if there are 2-and-2 or 2-and-1-and-1? The short answer is that I don't think there exists a function to do exactly what you want to do, but given some clarification on this point, it should not be hard to write one.

Comment: It is somewhat of a logical flaw, though, to compare `3 == "NA"`, in that a number does not equal a string. R is nice enough to coerce things for you, but there are many times when this silent casting will fail the intent.

Comment: @r2evans In terms of your first point if any of the columns have even one missing value it needs to be flagged, but I hadn't thought of how I would want the error displayed if multiple columns failed.  As far as the comparison between ' 3 == "NA" ' the actual value in my dataset would almost certainly be missing and not a string that is NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cond = cond = names(example)[which(!replace_na(a == c_across(b:d), F)) + 1] %>% 
                  paste(collapse = ",")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Note: The `+ 1` is because this looks up column names by index based on which did not pass. `+ 1` is to skip column `a` so that `cond` shows the correct column. `paste` is used in case there are multiple columns that do not meet the condition. They will be comma separated in `cond`.

Also as mentioned in the comments by @r2evans about coersion I modified `c <- c(1,2, "NA", "NA")` to be `c <- c(1,2, NA, NA)`.

**Output**

```
      a     b     c     d cond 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1     1     1 ""   
2     2     2     2     2 ""   
3     3     3    NA     3 "c"  
4     4     4    NA     4 "c"
```

---

**Multiple columns fail condition**

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
c <- c(1,2, NA, NA)
d <- c(1,2,3,6)

example <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

example %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cond = cond = names(example)[which(!replace_na(a == c_across(b:d), F)) + 1] %>% 
                  paste(collapse = ",")) %>% 
  ungroup()

      a     b     c     d cond 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1     1     1 ""   
2     2     2     2     2 ""   
3     3     3    NA     3 "c"  
4     4     4    NA     6 "c,d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing your vectors in a data frame and using `sapply` can work:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
c <- c(1,2, "NA", "NA")
d <- c(1,2,3,4)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

result <- sapply(2:4, function(x) identical(df$a, df[, x]))
result
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You would adjust the parameters inside `sapply` consistent with the dimensions of your actual data frame.  You could also `rbind` the `result` to the `df` with a dummy value inserted for column `a`:

```
result <- c(999, result)
df <- rbind(result, df)
df
    a b  c d
1 999 1  0 1
2   1 1  1 1
3   2 2  2 2
4   3 3 NA 3
5   4 4 NA 4
```

The logical `result` values are converted to integer for type integrity. The zeros in the result row indicate which columns failed the test.